# weblogic: debug ActiveDirectory authenticator

Tags: weblogic

With Weblogic 10.3.2.0,
I created a ActiveDirectory authenticator at Weblogic, as follows,
and I need to enable the debug.

If I enable all the server log with: Environment -> AdminServer -> Debug -> enable all "default" and all "weblogic"
I obtain the kind of debug that I need, such as:

```
####<Apr 12, 2012 3:56:36 PM CEST> <Debug> <SecurityRoleMap> <WINXP3> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1334238996125> <BEA-000000> <Evaluate urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in(MYGROUP,MYUSER) -> false>
```

However, enabling all the server log is too heavy.
What is the specific debug component that I need to enable to get the ActiveDirectory debug, such as the example above?
I tried with "weblogic->security->realm" and "weblogic->security->ldap", but it didn't work.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

Embedded LDAP has log files for debug output and access events. The location and name of these files is set in the /myserver/ldap/conf/vde.props file.

[Source](http://monduke.com/2006/02/22/weblogic-embedded-ldap-logging/)

Answer (score 0):

debug logs for all authentication providers including custom providers if any can be logged by enabling SecurityAtn flag on the weblogic debug loggger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Good answer (if it does works)! You could still improve your answer by adding a reference and perhaps how this flag can be set. For instance: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/idm/mishra-wls-auth-2157543.html =>  (1) Go to Servers > server_Instance. (2) Select WebLogic > Security > atn > DebugSecurityAtn. (3) Click the Enable button.